# List samba share when no one is connected?

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

How to list samba share when no one is connected (the `smbstatus` command only show actual samba connections) ?

So far, I found this command :

```shell
$ testparm -s 2>/dev/null | awk '/path/ && $3 !~ /share\/?$/{for(i=3;i<NF;++i)printf$i" ";print$i}'
/volume1/Archive 04
/volume2/Archive 05
/volume3/Archive 06
$
```

Is there an easier way ?

Comment: why does having someone connected make a difference to you? `smbclient -L <host>` should display the shares running on `host`. `smbtree` is another option. https://askubuntu.com/questions/102924/list-samba-shares-and-current-users

Comment: @FrankThomas Because the  `smbstatus` command only show samba connections when people are connected.

Comment: well, the options I suggested don't. they list the shares regardless of usage.